# Running a nginx server with SSl on port 8080 with apache2 running on port 80/443

Tags: bash, nginx, ssl, apache2

I have an apache2 server that works great with my .htaccess rules. I now want to run a different page that will not be affected by my current .htaccess rules using the same domain name but different port.

I have setup a shell script to automate setting this up but somewhere there seems to be a conflict of ports even though nginx should not be running on port 80 or 443.

```
Here is the script:

#!/bin/sh

read -p 'Enter domain name: ' domain
apt-get update && apt -y install nginx nginx-full    nginx-common
systemctl enable nginx.service && systemctl start nginx.service
echo '''


    server {

    root /var/www/madeup.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name madeup.com

listen [::]:8080 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 8080 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/madeup.com/fullchain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/madeup.com/privkey.pem; 
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 

  }

   

 ''' > /tmp/file.txt
 cd /tmp
 sed -i "s/madeup.com/$domain/g" file.txt
 cat file.txt
 mv file.txt /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$domain
 apt install -y python3-certbot-nginx && certbot --nginx 
 systemctl restart nginx.service
 rm -rf *.sh.*
```

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: What other files are in `/etc/ngins/sites-enabled`?

Comment: @miknik thanks...I still had the default site enabled. So simple but completely overlooked it!! I would mark this as correct but there is not tick!